# get records for the date in between dates

Tags: sql, teradata

Here is my table inventory

```
        FromDate     Todate           productid    description      qty
        ---------    --------          ---------   ------------    ----
rec1    8/8/2013     8/12/2013        1111          cream            5
rec2    8/13/2013    8/19/2013        1111          cream            10
rec3    8/20/2013    8/21/2013        1111          cream            20
```

Table dimdate

```
datedate
---------
8/13/2013
8/14/2013
.
.
8/19/2013
```

How to get the rec2 for date 8/15/2013 from inventory table?

I am using teradata database.

Comment: can you give us a sample Query that you have tried? maybe some Tables? so more information please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a WHERE clause to only get records greater than that date.

```
WHERE Yourdatefield >= Cast(('08/15/2013' (Date,Format 'mm/dd/yyyy')) As Date)
```

Comment: Declan thanks for reply . with your example i will get rec2 and rec3 as output right ?? how to get only rec 2

Comment: i am trying with between  logic .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense what you are trying to see is ,for a given date yo umake sure its between start and end dates.
Hence below where condition should get you the required record.

**where Startdate <=Yourdatefield  and enddate>=Yourdatefield**